# problem with define dimensions of variables fortran 77

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I found this one old fortran 77 program printed in one old book, and i typed in the program but it isnt running. When I give the dimensions of variables, appear the next:

```
       DIMENSION XN(20),YN(20),W(20),NUMAJ(20),NUMAAJ(20),SSW(20)
      1,NEJI(5,20),QX(20,20),QY(20,20),IACTE(20),N1(20),N2(20),X(20)
      2,Y(20),DD(20),TT(20),NUMAJA(20)
```

And the error code:

Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Please elaborate. How does it not work? Please approximate a [mcve].

Comment: Welcome, please take the welcome [tour] and read [ask]. You should describe how you are compiling your code, how you are running it and what exactly happens. Is there any error message? Which exact command do you use?

Comment: Tell us how you are compiling it and include the error messages you get.

Comment: "*after running*" - running what?

Comment: This is the right place to ask, but you have to ask differently. Please take the time to read the links you were given in the first two comments. The code is too much for us to debug, but odds are the problem is something simple (you're probably trying to compile it wrong, or something is missing). That's why we need more information, which should be clear if you read the links.

Comment: It's "statement" (not "statemetn"), "unexpected" (not "unexoexted"), etc. Are you retyping error messages instead of just copy/pasting them?

Comment: Your statements all start in column 5 (after 4 spaces of indentation). That's wrong. They should start in column 7 (after 6 spaces (or a label)).

Comment: sorry, yes You are on right. For the rows beginning with x Format (), i give back the messages that: unexpected element '\XE2' in format string at (1)

Comment: Stop posting crumbs of information in comments. [Edit] your question if you want to make it answerable.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the original and edited version shows still incorrect indenting: fixed format reserves columns 1-5 for labels, 6 for the continuation character and starting from 7 for the statements. If column 6 is not a space the line continues the previous line.

In the 3 line example above the characters "1" and "2" are the continuation characters of line 2 and 3, so they have to be exactly in column 6. The first line has no label or continuation character so it must start in column 7. The comment from  @melpomene was incomplete regarding continuation character and based on the old version where one space less was used (the edited version has one space too much).

Comment: Thank You @bbu but the characters "1" and "2" are exactly in column 6, now I found one problem that was the character "," the end of the rows, but after i give back the error message:source_file.f:18:7:

      1NEJI(5,20),QX(20,20),QY(20,20),IACTE(20),N1(20),N2(20),X(20)
       1
Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)